# CapabilityApi in wear 2.0 only works when using same package id

Tags: android, android-wear-2.0

I'm trying to use the CapabilityApi to find my standalone wear2 app from my phone, but it only seems to work if both the wear-app and the mobile-app share the same package id.

I follow the instructions at https://developer.android.com/wear/preview/features/standalone-apps.html for "Detecting your app on another device". I see no errors and I can se the Nodes as normal using the NodeApi I just wont get anything from the CapabilityApi unless both apps have the same package id. This feels like a throwback to wear1 with no standalone apps.

(the sample app at https://github.com/googlesamples/android-WearVerifyRemoteApp also stops working if you change the package id)

How would that would that work if I have more than one mobile-app that wants to talk to the same wear-app using CapabilityApi?

Does anyone know if this is the expected behaviour or am I doing something wrong?